# What is the correct syntax of using "ISNULL" inside ASP.NET code?

Tags: asp.net, sql

I'm trying to execute this chunk of code:

```
public List<CustomerCaseSearch> FindCustomerInfo(string searchCondition)
{
    var Query = "SELECT  CustomerProfile.CustomerID,CustomerProfile.CustomerName,    isNull(k.CustomerSince, '''') as CustomerSince, isNull(k.CustomerStatus,'''') as CustomerStatus," +
                "CustomerProfile.CustomerType, CustomerCase.CaseID" +
                " FROM CustomerProfile INNER JOIN" +
                " CustomerCase ON CustomerProfile.CustomerID = CustomerCase.CustomerID "+ searchCondition;

    var customerCaseSearch = _CustomerCaseSearchRepository.ExecuteQueryData<CustomerCaseSearch>(@Query);
    List<CustomerCaseSearch> aList = customerCaseSearch.ToList();
    return aList;
}
```

And I keep getting this exception message:

```
SQLException was unhandled by user code. 
Incorrect syntax near 'isNull'
```

I need to know, what is the correct syntax of using isNull inside an ASP.NET code where I need to put SQL Query?

Please note that I am a newby to professional development so my knowledge is quite low. Kind help anticipated and will be appreciated.

Comment: The syntax seems correct, what I don't see in your statement is aliasing anything to be `k`.

Comment: ISNULL is a valid MSSQL function, problem is something else.

Comment: The two pair of single quotes may be problematic.

Answer (score 3):

Your query comes out as:

```
SELECT      CustomerProfile.CustomerID,
            CustomerProfile.CustomerName,    
            isNull(k.CustomerSince, '''') as CustomerSince, 
            isNull(k.CustomerStatus,'''') as CustomerStatus,
            CustomerProfile.CustomerType, CustomerCase.CaseID 

FROM        CustomerProfile 

INNER JOIN  CustomerCase 
    ON      CustomerProfile.CustomerID = CustomerCase.CustomerID
```

Your calls to `ISNULL` refer to a table with alias `k`, but there is no table with that alias in your query.

It's worth noting that you've asked it to return a value that is a single apostrophe, if the value were NULL, so you *may* want to change that as well

Comment: Ok I edited my code as per your instruction, but still getting the same error. :/

Comment: what is the value of `searchCondition`?

Comment: I need to send only either of two values: open or close. Any one of them will be sent to searchCondition. I'm sending this value from a javascript file where I defined the query string.

Answer (score 1):

You are using table alias `k` that is nowhere found in your query that is why it is failing.

I reformatted it so it is easier to read, below is proper query:

```
SELECT cp.CustomerID, cp.CustomerName, isNull(cp.CustomerSince, '') as CustomerSince,
       isNull(cp.CustomerStatus, '') as CustomerStatus, cp.CustomerType, cc.CaseID
FROM CustomerProfile cp
INNER JOIN CustomerCase cc ON cp.CustomerID = cc.CustomerID
```

then you have to add your search string to the end.

Answer (score 0):

may be you missing a space:

```
var Query = "SELECT  CustomerProfile.CustomerID,CustomerProfile.CustomerName,    isNull(k.CustomerSince, '''') as CustomerSince, isNull(k.CustomerStatus,'''') as CustomerStatus," +
                " CustomerProfile.CustomerType, CustomerCase.CaseID" +
                " FROM CustomerProfile INNER JOIN" +
                " CustomerCase ON CustomerProfile.CustomerID = CustomerCase.CustomerID "+ searchCondition;
```

Comment: No I still keep getting errors. I corrected it, used '', but still the exception is thrown.

Comment: So please tell me is k alias for CustomerProfile?

Comment: No. That was a mistake. I wanted to use k as alias, but later decided not to use any alias, forgot to remove that k. :) :)

Comment: please try this answer again without any alias :D. I think it work now